# How to access Panel id from public function inside Repeater Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

I need to show list of years for which i have Photo albums. I use Repeater control for this and wrapper year inside a div control. I also pass current Year as `QueryString` . I need to show the current year in red as a background for div.  my panel always return null as i am not able to pass the `Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e`. How can i alter this code so that i can change the CssClass from code behind.

I can use another approach for same by using `Literal Control` & show my list of Years as List `<ul>`... which i can use & have full control over my list css.

Please advice how i can achieve this in best & effective way. I am also keep to get in done in the way i am trying to do it as it might be useful in future & very education for me

`http://localhost:65123/Gallery/Albums.aspx?Year=2011&PageID=38`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlbumsYears" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="AlbumPageYearListing">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hyplnkCat1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# getAlbumURLbyCat(Eval("Year"))%>'>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlYear" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAlbumYear" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Year")%>'></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.CS Code

```
protected String getAlbumURLbyCat(object Year)
{
    string url;
    int PageID = Helper.GetPageIDbyName("Albums.aspx", "en-us");
    url = "~/Albums.aspx?Year=" + Year + "&PageID=" + PageID;
    try
    {
        int CurYear = 0;
        CurYear = int.Parse(Request["Year"].ToString());
        int iYear = int.Parse(Year.ToString());
        //Image imgArticleList = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgArticleList") as Image;
        Panel pnlYear = (Panel)FindControl("pnlYear");

       // Panel pnlYear = (Panel) 
        if (CurYear == iYear)
        {
            pnlYear.CssClass = "AlbumPageYearListingCurrent";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED ISSUE by using following code

```
protected void rptAlbumsYears_ItemBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            int Year = Convert.ToInt32(drv["Year"]);
            Repeater Repeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptAlbumsYears");
            Panel pnlYear = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlYear");
            int CurYear = 0;
            CurYear = int.Parse(Request["Year"].ToString());
            if (CurYear == Year)
            {
                pnlYear.CssClass = "AlbumPageYearListingCurrent";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```